# installing a drywall ceiling where drop ceiling was

Tags: ceiling

I'm opening a brand new barbershop and I'm remolding my new space. It use to have a nasty, dirty, and bent drop ceiling. My space is a 29'x60' open space. I am also installing 2 interior walls to seperate my barbershop from the salon. What would be the best way to install the ceiling? I was going to use 2"x10"s to hang on the cement block wall with topcons so I could attach my joist hangers on. Then I was going to use a 2"x6"x16's for the ceiling joist. I figured if i attached the 2"x6"x16' together where they over lap, then they would work. I was going to use 4 rows of (5) 2"x4"x12"s as runners on top of the 2"x6"ceiling joist. Also, where those runners connected to the ceiling joist, I was going to attach a 2"x4"x40" from the existing truss to the ceiling joist so it will support 5/8" drywall and lights

Comment: why do you need to have a closed ceiling?

Comment: you are planning to splice 2x6s at 16' to get the 29' ?  And you have no support under the splice?  Can you draw a section (vertical slice) of this arrangement?

Comment: It would be good to see a picture of what the ceiling area looks like with the dropped ceiling removed.